# Can we have multiple script function in for <xsl:value-of /> element

Tags: xml, xslt

Is the below statement valid:

```
<xsl:with-param name="IsEnabled">
     <xsl:value-of select="script:IsCustomerEnabled('abc') and script:IsBrandEnabled('xyz')"/>
</xsl:with-param>
```

What will be the output when both of then returns Enabled?

Also, what will the comma (,) operator do instead of and:

```
<xsl:with-param name="IsEnabled">
     <xsl:value-of select="script:IsCustomerEnabled('abc'), script:IsBrandEnabled('xyz')"/>
</xsl:with-param>
```

Comment: Start reading a tutorial on XPath or use the spec https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-logical-expressions, https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#construct_seq. That assumes you use an XSLT 2.0 processor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If both calls return true then the result of applying the "and" operator will be the xs:boolean value true, which xsl:value-of will display as the string "true".

The result of applying the comma operator (which requires XPath 2.0) will be a sequence containing two booleans (true, true), which xsl:value-of (in 2.0) will display as "true true".

Using xsl:value-of as a child of a variable binding element such as xsl:with-param is usually incorrect, since it has the effect of constructing a document node containing a single text node containing the actual value converted to a string. There's no reason for all those conversions: use the select attribute of xsl:with-param instead.

Sometimes this just causes inefficiency, but sometimes it can cause horrible bugs. For example if you use

```
<xsl:variable name="option">
  <xsl:value-of select="false()"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:if test="$option">...
```

then the test evaluates to true, because the value of $option is a node, and the effective boolean value of a non-empty node-set is always true regardless of the content of the node.