# Create empty Column space when <xsl:otherwise> is true

Tags: xslt, whitespace

I am transforming an XML into PDF Document using XSLT 1.0 and Groovy. When my table is rendered in PDF, XSLT is inserting Doc Link in every column, whereas my requirement is to render empty white space in the column when no link is found in the XML

```
    <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black">
    <xsl:variable name="link"><xsl:value-of select="link/text()"/</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="space" select="'&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;'"/>
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$link">
               <fo:basic-link external-destination="url({$link})" color="blue" text-decoration="underline">Doc Link</fo:basic-link></xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="$space"/></xsl:otherwise>                      
        </xsl:choose>
    </fo:block>
```

Could it be because of Groovy? If yes how can I fix it?

Comment: The test will always evaluate to true.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44785480/can-we-have-multiple-script-function-in-for-xslvalue-of-element/44787052#44787052

Comment: so how do I change the always true behaviour of test to execute otherwise ? Pls help

Comment: I updated my code to include white space using a variable , but still otherwise is not getting executed ! Pls help I am really stuck and looking for some expert help :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @dave pointed out, you've fallen into the trap I described earlier today in [Can we have multiple script function in for <xsl:value-of /> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44785480)

You need to replace

```
<xsl:variable name="link"><xsl:value-of select="link/text()"/</xsl:variable>
```

with

```
<xsl:variable name="link" select="link/text()"/>
```

I don't know why this mistake is so common, since the correct code is much shorter and simpler than the incorrect code.

Comment: The protocol on StackOverflow is to say thanks by accepting the answer: click on the "tick mark".